# how to save TfidfVectorizer and use it again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, text-mining

I want to save a text classifier. I am using a TfidfVectorizer in my code like this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=tokenize, lowercase=True, stop_words='english',
                             max_features=1100)
corpus_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data_df.Text.tolist() + test_data_df.Text.tolist())

# Convering the document term matrix to numpy nd array
corpus_data_features_nd = (corpus_data_features.toarray())
calibrated_svc.fit(X=corpus_data_features_nd[0:len(train_data_df)], y=train_data_df.Domain)
test_pred=calibrated_svc.predict(corpus_data_features_nd[len(train_data_df):])
```

so afer training I can save a model and reuse it. but when I want to reuse the model I must create corpus_data_features again:

```
 corpus_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data_df.Text.tolist() + test_data_df.Text.tolist())
```

and this kind of saving classifier could not help the speed of classifying.
how can I split corpus_data_features into two part and use a saved vector for train_data_df  and then add test_data_df when I load my model?

Comment: Use joblib or pickle to save the tfidfvectorizer

Comment: After saving, it is useless because of must calculate a new tfidf with new words+ training data. I think I must split 'corpus_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data_df.Text.tolist() + test_data_df.Text.tolist())' but how?

Comment: No. Only call fit() or fit_transform() on training data. To convert the testing data, only call transform(). So its not useless. Please check the usage. When you do fit_transform on testing data, you are leaking knowledge about unseen data to the model and it will give unrealistic results.

Comment: corpus_train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data_df.Text.tolist())
corpus_test_data_features = vectorizer.transform(test_data_df.Text.tolist())
I used this and the results are surprisingly better than before!thank you @VivekKumar.
I think now I can save TfidfVectorizer by vocabulary property to a dump file by pickle.

Comment: You can store the whole tfidfvectorizer object

Comment: Please refer to the stack overflow link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337642/5117127