# Error predicting: X has n features per sample, expecting m

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I got the following code, where I transform a text to tf:

```
...
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(dataset['documents'],dataset['classes'],test_size=test_percentil)
#Term document matrix
count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, Ngram), min_df=1, max_features=MaxVocabulary)
x_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_counts=count_vect.transform(x_test)
#Term Inverse-Frequency
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit(x_train_counts)
lista=tf_transformer.get_params()
x_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(x_train_counts)
x_test_tf=tf_transformer.transform(x_test_counts)
...
```

Then, I train a model and save it using pickle.
The problem comes when, in another program, I try to predict new data.
Basically, I got:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), min_df=1, max_features=None)
x_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(dataset['documents'])

#Term Inverse-Frequency
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit(x_counts)
x_tf = tf_transformer.transform(x_train_counts)

model.predict(x_tf)
```

When I execute this code, the output is

> ValueError: X has 8933 features per sample; expecting 7488

I know this is a problem with the TfIdf representation, and I hear that I need to use the same tf_transformer and vectorizer to get the expected input shape, but I don't know how to achieve this.
I can store the others transformers and vectorizers, but I have tried using different combinations and I got nothing.

Comment: why do you initizalize again the `count_vect` and `tf_transformer` ?

Comment: because I'm in another python code

Comment: can't you save and load the TFidf result with `pickle` or `joblib`?

Comment: is it helping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788047/keep-tfidf-result-for-predicting-new-content-using-scikit-for-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
a = pd.Series(["hello, this is me", "hello this is me too"])
b = pd.Series(["hello, this is John", "hi it's Doe"])
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit(a)
joblib.dump(tfidf, 'path_to/tfidf.pkl')
tfidf = joblib.load('path_to/tfidf.pkl')
tfidf.transform(b).todense()
```

Comment: used fit_transform on the tfidfVectorizer() instead of fit. what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

In another program you are instantiating a new object, which will not know that previous data has those many columns.

You need to save the `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` the same way as you saved the model and load them the same way in another program.

Also, you can just use the [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) instead of CountVectorizer + TfidfTransformer, because it does the combined thing and will make your work (saving and loading them easier).

So during training do this:

```
...
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(dataset['documents'],dataset['classes'],test_size=test_percentil)
#Term document matrix
tf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, Ngram), min_df=1, max_features=MaxVocabulary, use_idf=True)
x_train_tf = tf_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_tf = tf_vect.transform(x_test)

...
```