# How to run model on new data that requires pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a model that runs the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1,'a'], ['tom', 15,5,'a'], ['tom', 14,1,'a'], ['tom', 15,4,'b'], ['tom', 18,1,'b'], ['tom', 15,6,'a'], ['tom', 17,3,'a']
       , ['tom', 14,7,'b'], ['tom',16 ,6,'a'], ['tom', 22,2,'a'],['matt', 10,1,'c'], ['matt', 15,5,'b'], ['matt', 14,1,'b'], ['matt', 15,4,'a'], ['matt', 18,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,6,'a'], ['matt', 17,3,'a']
       , ['matt', 14,7,'c'], ['matt',16 ,6,'b'], ['matt', 10,2,'b']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 

print(df.head(2))
  Name  Attempts  Score Category
0  tom        10      1        a
1  tom        15      5        a
```

Then I have created a dummy df to use in the model using the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df_dum = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(df_dum.head(2))
  Attempts  Score  Name_matt  Name_tom  Category_a  Category_b  Category_c
0        10      1          0         1           1           0           0
1        15      5          0         1           1           0           0
```

Then I have created the following model:

```
#Model

X = df_dum.drop(('Score'),axis=1)
y = df_dum['Score'].values

#Training Size
train_size = int(X.shape[0]*.7)
X_train = X[:train_size]
X_test = X[train_size:]
y_train = y[:train_size]
y_test = y[train_size:]


#Fit Model
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)


#Send predictions back to dataframe
Z = model.predict(X_test)
zz = model.predict_proba(X_test)

df.loc[train_size:,'predictions']=Z
dfpredictions = df.dropna(subset=['predictions'])

print(dfpredictions)
    Name  Attempts  Score Category  predictions
14  matt        18      1        a          1.0
15  matt        15      6        a          1.0
16  matt        17      3        a          1.0
17  matt        14      7        c          1.0
18  matt        16      6        b          1.0
19  matt        10      2        b          1.0
```

Now I have new data which i would like to predict:

```
newdata = [['tom', 10,'a'], ['tom', 15,'a'], ['tom', 14,'a']]

newdf = pd.DataFrame(newdata, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Category']) 

print(newdf)

 Name  Attempts Category
0  tom        10        a
1  tom        15        a
2  tom        14        a
```

Then create dummies and run prediction

```
newpredict = pd.get_dummies(newdf)

predict = model.predict(newpredict)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: X has 3 features per sample; expecting 6
```

Which makes sense because there are no categories `b` and `c` and no name called `matt`.

My question is how is the best way to set this model up given my new data wont always have the full set of columns used in the original data. Each day i have new data so I'm not quite sure of the most efficient and error free way.

This is an example data - my dataset has 2000 columns when running `pd.get_dummies`. Thanks very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208115/error-predicting-x-has-n-features-per-sample-expecting-m

Comment: I remember a lengthy discussion on this site, in which people concluded that it's better to use `sklearn` one-hot encoder for this exact reason.

Comment: @NicolasGervais's got it. If you use the same OneHotEncoder object, it will remember how many total columns there were when you fit it for the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me explain Nicolas and BlueSkyz's recommendation a bit more in detail.

`pd.get_dummies` is useful when you are sure that there will not be any new categories for a specific categorical variable in production/new data set, e.g. Gender, Products, etc. based on your Company or Database's internal data classification/consistency rules.

However, for the majority of machine learning tasks where you can expect to have new categories in the future which were not used in model training, `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` should be the standard choice. `handle_unknown` parameter of `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` can be set to `'ignore'` to do just that: ignore new categories when applying the encoder in future. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html):

> Whether to raise an error or ignore if an unknown categorical feature is present during transform (default is to raise). When this parameter is set to ‘ignore’ and an unknown category is encountered during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros. In the inverse transform, an unknown category will be denoted as None

The full flow based on LabelEncoding and OneHotEncoding for your example is as below:

```
# Create a categorical boolean mask
categorical_feature_mask = df.dtypes == object
# Filter out the categorical columns into a list for easy reference later on in case you have more than a couple categorical columns
categorical_cols = df.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()

# Instantiate the OneHotEncoder Object
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse = False)
# Apply ohe on data
ohe.fit(df[categorical_cols])
cat_ohe = ohe.transform(df[categorical_cols])

#Create a Pandas DataFrame of the hot encoded column
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(cat_ohe, columns = ohe.get_feature_names(input_features = categorical_cols))
#concat with original data and drop original columns
df_ohe = pd.concat([df, ohe_df], axis=1).drop(columns = categorical_cols, axis=1)

# The following code is for your newdf after training and testing on original df
# Apply ohe on newdf
cat_ohe_new = ohe.transform(newdf[categorical_cols])
#Create a Pandas DataFrame of the hot encoded column
ohe_df_new = pd.DataFrame(cat_ohe_new, columns = ohe.get_feature_names(input_features = categorical_cols))
#concat with original data and drop original columns
df_ohe_new = pd.concat([newdf, ohe_df_new], axis=1).drop(columns = categorical_cols, axis=1)

# predict on df_ohe_new
predict = model.predict(df_ohe_new)
```

Output (that you can assign back to newdf):

```
array([1, 1, 1])
```

However, if you really want to use `pd.get_dummies` only, then the following can work as well:

```
newpredict = newpredict.reindex(labels = df_dum.columns, axis = 1, fill_value = 0).drop(columns = ['Score'])
predict = model.predict(newpredict)
```

The above code snippet will make sure that you have the same columns in your new dummies df (newpredict) as the original df_dum (with `0` values) and drop the `'Score'` column. Output here is same as above. This code will ensure that any categorical values present in the new data set but now in the original trained data will be removed while keeping the order of the columns same as that in the original df.

EDIT:
One thing I forgot to add is that `pd.get_dummies` is usually much faster to execute than `sklearn.OneHotEncoder`

Comment: Glad to be of help @SOK. Let me know if you face any issues while implementing it.

Comment: thanks @finlytics-hub. The only issue I am having at the moment is an `TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number'` when I am at the `ohe.fit(dfmodel[categorical_cols])` stage. Any ideas to debug?

Comment: @SOK Can you check the output of `categorical_cols`? It should be like this `['Name', 'Category']`. And I assume the `dfmodel` that you are referring in `ohe.fit` is exactly the same `df` that you defined in your original post?

Comment: yes sorry `dfmodel` is the same as `df` . When I debug it lists `categorical_cols` as you said and in my example it has about 7 columns (which are all categorical) so im not too sure why

Comment: (I am applying to my bigger model) which has more columns that the above question

Comment: hmmm..that's strange. Unfortunately I will not be able to help you out much without having access to your code and data. Maybe try it first on the smaller dataset that you had in your original post and then take it from there once you have a working example?

Comment: Yes thanks I will try that. In general any non `int` or `float` should appear in the `categorical_cols` output?

Comment: `categorical_cols` should have a list of all categorical variables in your df. In your original contrived df, there were only 2 categorical variables which I selected using this: `categorical_feature_mask = df.dtypes == object` assuming that all variables of `object` type would be categorical. If you want to, you can skip this step and manually assign all categorical variables like this: `categorical_cols = ['Name', 'Category', 'xyz', 'abc']`.

Comment: Great - thanks. I just tried on a smaller `df` and could reproduced the error if one of the non categorical columns has a non `int` value. So i might try and reassisgn the non categorical columns to `.astype(int)` or `.astype(float)`. Will let you  know how i go!